# Xaml designer doesn't show content of a usercontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, designer

We have a specialized TabItem defined in xaml:

```
<TabItem  x:Class="MyApp.MyViewTab" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyApp">
    <my:MyView />
</TabItem>
```

and code behind: `public class MyViewTab : TabItem`.
And `MyView` is a `UserControl`:

`MyView` is correctly shown in the xaml designer and also at run time correctly displayed as the content of the TabItem.

Why does the xaml designer not display the content of `MyView`? It is a gray rectangle, top half light-gray, bottom half darker-gray.

Comment: Close designer, open designer, rebuild your project, refresh designer, ...click around :) This should help

Comment: @devhedgehog: I like the suggestion, tried but no. Perhaps because TabItem does not inherit from UserControl?

Comment: I see now you have x:Class set on TabItem. Yes, designer needs sort of to have Window as root or Page or any navigation control. To read more about navigation take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I should accept an answer and "the designer needs a navigation control like window, page as root" is the answer.

Comment: Shall I post you this?

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the screen between the UI designer and the code and then clicking on the code line where you declared your `MyView` control. This should focus the designer on the contents of that `TabItem`:

```
<TabItem  x:Class="MyApp.MyViewTab" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyApp">
    <my:MyView />   <!--Click here-->
</TabItem>
```

If you click anywhere within the `TabItem`, it should do the same.

Comment: @Ssheridan: unfortunately this doesn't work on my computer (VS2013), also tried via Document Outline, but no. Perhaps because TabItem does not inherit from UserControl?

Comment: It sounds like good old Visual Studio has been taking away former useful functionality again.

Comment: Blend 2013 or VS2012 don't show the content either, well I'll ignore the issue.